# How To Use OR Operator In Where Condition-Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can someone help me that how to use OR operator in where condition in `ActiveRecord` in Rails.

I want like below,

     `x=[1,2,3]
     y=['a','b','c']
     Z.where(:name => y OR :val => x)`

Here in table `Z` we have two fields called name and val. And i need to fetch those record `where name in ('a','b','c') OR val in (1,2,3)`.

Comment: `Z.where('name IN (?) OR val IN (?)', y, x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the String argument to `where`.

```
Z.where('name IN (?) OR val IN (?)', y, x)
```

Using this parameterized format, `y` and `x` will be sanitized automatically.